# Summing by active column vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
'Find & Copy Column for Actual Curtailed
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Worksheets("Report")
            Range("A2:AC2").Find(What:="Actual Curtailed").ActiveCell.Select
            Range("S20") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range(Column(ActiveCell.Column))).Copy
```

This code brings a compile error, I am presuming that I am doing some wrong by summing the column with where the active cell is.

I am trying to fine "actual curtailed", get the column number, and put the summation of that column in row S20.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code will do what you intend.

```
Dim SumClm      As Variant
Dim SumRng      As Range

With Worksheets("Report")
    SumClm = Application.Match("Actual Curtailed", .Rows(2), 0)
    If Not IsError(SumClm) Then
        ' from row 3 to the end of the column
        Set SumRng = .Range(.Cells(3, SumClm), .Cells(.Rows.Count, SumClm).End(xlUp))
       .Cells(20, "S").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumRng)
    End If
End With
```

If the column isn't found S20 will remain blank.

Answer (score 0):

I just did few edits to your code

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Report")
Range("A2:AC2").Find(What:="Actual Curtailed").Activate
Range("S20") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns(ActiveCell.Column))
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, please accept my answer with upvote

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have 15 upvotes, so I can't upvote you apparently